# Binding a value to a control

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm currently writing some code in PyQt4 that takes a value and a control and binds the value to the control.  Once the user saves the form it will unbind all the values and save it back to a custom object (in this case [QgsFeature](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html)).

At the moment, I have the bind and unbind code which uses `if`/`elif` statements to work out the control type and then use the correct methods to bind the value, like so:

```
def bindValueToControl(self, control, value):
        """
        Binds a control to the supplied value.
        Raises BindingError() if control is not supported.

        control - QWidget based control that takes the new value
        value - A QVariant holding the value
        """
        if isinstance(control, QCalendarWidget):
            control.setSelectedDate(QDate.fromString(value.toString(), Qt.ISODate))

        elif isinstance(control, QListWidget):
            items = control.findItems(value.toString(), Qt.MatchExactly)
            try:
                control.setCurrentItem(items[0])
                control.currentItemChanged.emit(None, items[0])
            except IndexError:
                pass

        elif isinstance(control, QLineEdit) or isinstance(control, QTextEdit):
            control.setText(value.toString())

        elif isinstance(control, QCheckBox) or isinstance(control, QGroupBox):
            control.setChecked(value.toBool())

        elif isinstance(control, QPlainTextEdit):
            control.setPlainText(value.toString())

        elif isinstance(control, QComboBox):
            # Add items stored in the database
            query = QSqlQuery()
            query.prepare("SELECT value FROM ComboBoxItems WHERE control = :contorl")
            query.bindValue(":control", control.objectName())
            query.exec_()
            while query.next():
                newvalue = query.value(0).toString()
                if not newvalue.isEmpty():
                    control.addItem(newvalue)

            itemindex = control.findText(value.toString())
            if itemindex == -1:
                control.insertItem(0,value.toString())
                control.setCurrentIndex(0)
            else:
                control.setCurrentIndex(itemindex)

        elif isinstance(control, QDoubleSpinBox):
            double, passed = value.toDouble()
            control.setValue(double)

        elif isinstance(control, QSpinBox):
            integer, passed = value.toInt()
            control.setValue(integer)
        else:
            raise BindingError(control, value.toString(), "Unsupported widget %s" % control)
```

for unbind:

```
def unbindFeature(self, qgsfeature):
    """
    Unbinds the feature from the form saving the values back to the QgsFeature.
    """
    for index, control in self.fieldtocontrol.items():
            value = None
            if isinstance(control, QLineEdit):
                value = control.text()

            elif isinstance(control, QTextEdit) or isinstance(control, QPlainTextEdit):
                value = control.toPlainText()

            elif isinstance(control, QCalendarWidget):
                value = control.selectedDate().toString(Qt.ISODate)

            elif isinstance(control, QCheckBox) or isinstance(control, QGroupBox):
                value = 0
                if control.isChecked():
                    value = 1
            elif isinstance(control, QComboBox):
                value = control.currentText()
                if control.isEditable():
                    self.saveComboValues(control, value)

            elif isinstance(control, QDoubleSpinBox) or isinstance(control, QSpinBox):
                value = control.value()

            elif isinstance(control, QDateTimeEdit):
                value = control.dateTime().toString(Qt.ISODate)

            elif isinstance(control, QListWidget):
                item = control.currentItem()
                if item:
                    value = item.text()
                else:
                    return QString("")
```

I can't help but feel this is a little dirty looking.  Is there a nicer, more maintainable, way to handle something like this.

Comment: This post might help you [Pythonic way to avoid a mountain of if…else statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640598/pythonic-way-to-avoid-a-mountain-of-if-else-statements) The concept of [dispatch table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715457/how-do-you-implement-a-dispatch-table-in-your-language-of-choice) is also a good way of handling large if-else or switch block.

Answer (score 3):

To expand a little further on part of sky py's answer, you could try something like the following

```
class BaseControlHandler:
    def __init__( self, control ):
        self.control = control
    def bind( self, value ): 
        raise SuitableException()
    def unbind( self ):
        raise SuitableException()

class LineEditHandler( BaseControlHandler ):
    def __init__( self, control ):
        BaseControlHandler.__init__( self, control )
    def bind( self, value ):
        self.control.setText(value.toString())
    def unbind( self ):
        return self.control.text()

class CheckBoxHandler( BaseContolHandler ):
    # etc
```

You could then set up a dictionary mapping the control type to the appropriate handler:

```
handlers = { QtLineEdit: LineEditHandler, QtCheckBox: CheckBoxHandler, ... }
```

So your main block of if..elif.. becomes

```
for ctltype in handlers:
    if isinstance( control, ctltype ):
        ctl = handlers[ctltype]( control )
        ctl.bind( value ) # or unbind
        break
```

You'll unfortunately need to keep the `handlers=` line and the subclasses in step together.